# How to use properties of bevel tool?

Tags: properties, bevel

Is it possible with Bevel tool to type desired values directly, instead of applying it only by mouse movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just stop dragging and the dialog box to tweak everything will appear at the bottom (you just might need to expand it).

Comment: It's not working. I am using blender 2.8.

Comment: did you click anywhere after dragging the bevel?

Comment: I found it in lower left corner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you bevel with the mouse, then press F9 to get the last action menu to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

You can bevel and use the Adjust last operation menu as Francois said, or you can while dragging the mouse to adjust the bevel width press:

A: to adjust the amount of width

M: to cycle through width type

P: to adjust the bevel profile

S: to adjust the number of segments

All these proprieties can be set using the numbpad.